# How do I fix this error in my addAfter() for a DoublyLinkedList using a sentinel? AssertionError: Expected exception: NoSuchElementException

Tags: nullpointerexception, nodes, addition, doubly-linked-list

**Code:**

```
 * Inserts a new value in the list after the given Node.  For example,
 * if the list is 1,2,3,4, and listNode is 2 then addAfter(listNode,9) should give
 * 1,2,9,3,4.
 * @param listNode the new value should be inserted after this node  
 * @param t the value to insert
 * @return the newly created Node
 */
public Node<T> addAfter(Node<T> listNode, T t) 
{

    Node<T> newNode =new Node<T>(t, listNode, listNode.next);
    newNode.next=listNode.next;
    listNode.next=newNode;
    newNode.prev=listNode;
    size++;
    return newNode;
}
```

I also receive a `NullPointerException` error .

how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To add an element before/after of any element in the linked list, search for the value instead of Node object itself.

Because the Node object which you are passing as argument of addAfter method is not the same as the the Node of same value in the list, because their references are not same. Lets say we are calling the method like this by creating the Node object -

```
Node searchNode = new Node(10);
addAfter(searchNode, 10);
```

We should search for value of node after/before which we need to add the newly created node. Here is the sample code and i have not used generics here, based on your requirement you can use your generics -

```
public Node addAfter(int searchVal, int val) 
{
        Node newNode =new Node(val);
        Node temp = head.getNext();
        Node q = null;
        if(tail.prev.getData() == searchVal)
        {
             newNode.setNext(tail);
             newNode.setPrev(tail.prev);
             tail.prev.setNext(newNode);
             tail = newNode;
             length++;
             return newNode;
        }
        while(temp != null)
        {
            if(temp.getData() == searchVal)
            {
                q = temp;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        if(q != null)
        {
            newNode.setNext(q.getNext());
            newNode.setPrev(q);
            q.getNext().setPrev(newNode);
            q.setNext(newNode);

        }

        length++;
        return newNode;
}
```

Lets say you have linkedList which looks like this - [10,20,30,40] and you want to insert after 20 then call would be :

```
Node insertedNode = addAfter(20, 25);
```

Hope this help.